# configuring persistent static route in debian

Tags: linux, debian, route

I know how to add route for network trough specific gateway on specific device:
in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
up route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.0.0.2
```

But what if I need to add route for a specific IP instead of network, how the command would alter, I presume this `-net` would change to something else ?

Answer (score 2):

For a specific host, you need to change the `-net` to `-host`, and just specify the IP instead of including the netmask.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest switching to the modern iprotue tools, which have a consistent syntax for hosts and networks:

```
up ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 via 10.0.0.2 # network
up ip route add 10.0.0.0/32 via 10.0.0.2 # host
```

You can use any prefix length you want, the syntax remains the same.

You can optionally add in a `dev eth0` (or similar) to make sure the traffic goes over that device, even if you happen to have another route to 10.0.0.2.

`route` and friends have been obsolete on Linux for over a decade.