# Static route VS Gateway Debian

Tags: linux, debian, route

Why setting Static route for server do not works same way as Setting the Gateway
for instance if the host is `10.0.0.11` and gateway with internet `10.0.0.2`
if I'm adding `10.0.0.2` as a gateway in `/etc/network/interfaces`
it works fine, I can ping let say google.ie so server is getting trough `10.0.0.2` in to the internet just fine

But if I'm adding it as a route:

```
up route add -host 10.0.0.11 gw 10.0.0.2
```

route is there but ping do not goes trough to let say ping google.ie
I may be wrong but it shouldn't work the same way ?

Comment: The `-host` argument is to specify a host which may be reached via the specified gateway, not to give the IP address of the local machine.  To add a _default_ route, you would use `route add default gw 10.0.0.2`

Comment: This is a followup question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/378512/ is it not?

Comment: Yes it is , we are working on essay with my friend, I Understand -host argument is not giving an IP, it specifies the host and I understand the traffic from that host should be routed trough specified Gateway , which in case is 10.0.0.2 ,,  In my understanding the principle is the same as default gateway works, routes the traffic from host 10.0.0.11 trough the same gateway 10.0.0.2 ...

Comment: @OkLin, the given `route` command routes the traffic _to_ host 10.0.0.11 through the gateway 10.0.0.2.

Comment: @user45566274 , ok so I understand it works oposit way than Default gateway...   SO then if I'll add the route up route add -host 10.0.0.2 gw 10.0.0.11 on the machine 10.0.0.2  with the internet. traffic will go trough ?

Answer (score 0):

The gateway is often referred to as the default route. If you add a default route to your routing table, you say in fact that if the routing table does not have a specific next hop for the requested destination address it should forward it to the default route address (the gateway).

Regular desktops/notebooks or just say workstations normally don't have multiple connected network interfaces at the same time and therefore don't act as router hence the almost empty routing table with only a gateway address where all outgoing traffic should be forwarded to.

When you setup a VPN connection for instance and then have a look to the routing table you will see that the routing table is expanded with several static routes for the networks to be reached through the VPN connection.

The routing table can be viewed by issuing `netstat -rn` and you can read more information in the manual page `man netstat` and `man route`